# Virtual function problem after casting template class instance

Tags: c++, templates, casting, virtual-functions, reinterpret-cast

I'm creating a library in C++ and I would like release some of the objects anytime I want. With raw pointers I couldn't notify the user that the pointer is no longer valid, with `shared_ptr` I couldn't release the object if the user has her/his own `shared_ptr` to it. So I decided to write my own smart pointer(ish) class. My goal was to create a class which counts the references and releases the memory if the reference count reaches 0, which is similar to `shared_ptr`, however it has a `destroy` method which releases the memory. Also the user can ask it whether or not the memory is still valid (or released).

The `pointer_wrapper` class contains the raw pointer and the reference count. As I said earlier, it releases the raw pointer if the reference count reaches 0 or if the user calls the `destroy` method.

```
template<class T> class pointer_wrapper {
private:
    T* raw_pointer;
    int32_t reference_count = 1;
public:
    pointer_wrapper(T* const raw_pointer): raw_pointer(raw_pointer) { }
    T* get_raw_pointer() const { return raw_pointer; }
    void increase_reference_count() { reference_count++; }
    void decrease_reference_count() {
        reference_count--;
        if(reference_count == 0) {
            delete this;
        }
    }
    int32_t get_reference_count() const { return reference_count; }
    void destroy() {
        if(raw_pointer != nullptr) {
            delete raw_pointer;
            raw_pointer = nullptr;
        }
    }
    ~pointer_wrapper() { destroy(); }
};
```

But the `pointer_wrapper` class is just for internal use, the library's user will always get a `ptr` instance. The user can copy the `ptr` object but all the copied `ptr` objects' `pw` variable will point to the same `pointer_wrapper`. This way if I call one of the `ptr` objects' `destroy` method, all the other `ptr` objects' `is_valid` method will return `false`. So if the library releases an object, the user will know this if she/he calls the `is_valid` method before use.

```
template<class T> class ptr {
private:
    pointer_wrapper<T>* pw;
public:
    ptr(T* const raw_pointer) { pw = new pointer_wrapper<T>(raw_pointer); }
    ptr(pointer_wrapper<T>* const pw): pw(pw) { pw->increase_reference_count(); }
    ptr(const ptr<T>& other_ptr) {
        pw = other_ptr.pw;
        pw->increase_reference_count();
    }
    ptr<T>& operator=(const ptr<T>& other_ptr) {
        pw->decrease_reference_count();
        pw = other_ptr.pw;
        pw->increase_reference_count();
        return *this;
    }
    T* operator->() const { return pw->get_raw_pointer(); }
    int32_t get_reference_count() const { return pw->get_reference_count(); }
    bool is_valid() const { return pw->get_raw_pointer() != nullptr; }

    // the problem is probably here
    template<class X> ptr<X> convert() const { return ptr<X>(reinterpret_cast<pointer_wrapper<X>*>(pw)); }

    void destroy() { pw->destroy(); }
    ~ptr() { pw->decrease_reference_count(); }
};
```

The general pattern is that I have an exported interface-like class with only pure virtual methods and I have a implementation class (not exported, hidden in the dll) which inherits from the interface-like class.

```
static ptr<window_system> create() { return ptr<window_system>(new wm_glfw_window_system()); }
```

This works fine, until I try to cast it by calling the `convert` method. If I call a method on a converted `ptr` object, I get an error like this:

> Exception thrown at 0x0000000000000000 in example_1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.

```
ptr<window_system>(new wm_glfw_window_system())->create_window(...); // works fine
ptr<wm_glfw_window_system>(new wm_glfw_window_system())->create_window(...); // works fine
ptr<wm_glfw_window_system>(new wm_glfw_window_system()).convert<window_system>()->create_window(...); // error
ptr<window_system>(new wm_glfw_window_system()).convert<wm_glfw_window_system>()->create_window(...); // error
```

So I guess I have some problem with that `convert` method and the `reinterpret_cast`. But if I'm correct, I can't use other casts because the class `ptr<window_system>` and `ptr<wm_glfw_window_system>` are not related even though the `window_system` and the `wm_glfw_window_system` classes are related.

So my questions are:

- Is there a better way of archiving my goals (eg. a library with the appropriate pointer type)?
- Do my classes make any sense?
- How can I write my `convert` method to work properly (it has to support downcasting)?

Comment: *“I can't use other casts”* → You cannot use `reinterpret_cast` either. The only difference is the compiler will let you do it. Your program will still be wrong, and a crash or other *interesting result* is expected.

Comment: What happens if code A is in the middle of using the pointer when code B destroys it?

Comment: As far as I understand, you would have to do a `dynamic_cast` on the internal pointer type and not the wrapper.  You have to know that in C++ the compiler adjust a pointer when you do a `static_cast` or a `dynamic_cast`. `reinterpret_cast` can almost only used to convert to a temporary type and then convert back to exact original type and it useful mainly to work with API that allow a user defined pointer to be passed... For a specific compiler, there might be some other use of `reinterpret_cast` but they might not be portable.

Comment: Maybe custom deleter and (with `std::shared_ptr`) /or `std::weak_ptr` are the things you want

Comment: spectras, Phil1970: alright, so using the `reinterpret_cast` is not a good idea,  
Yakk - Adam Nevraumont: in my case, it can't really happen, Phil1970: but if i'm correct, this deleter will only be called when the last `shared_ptr` destroyed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinterpet cast.

Replace the single pointer to a pointer wrapper with a pointer to the object and a reference counting helper.

Support static, implicit and dynamic casts in the pointer to object which keep the same reference counter.

(This is roughly how shared_ptr works).

Your problem, other than your code is exhibiting undefined behavior, is that a pointer to base and derived need not have the same value.

Answer (score 1):

> with `shared_ptr` I couldn't release the object if the user has her/his own `shared_ptr` to it.
> Is there a better way of archiving my goals (eg. a library with the appropriate pointer type)?

It seems you just have to give `std::weak_ptr` to your user.
If you don't want them to convert and store the `std::shared_ptr`, you might wrap it in a class, something like:

```
template <class T> class
pointer_wrapper {
private:
    std::weak_ptr<T> pointer;
public:
    pointer_wrapper(std::weak_ptr<T> pointer): pointer(pointer) {}

    template <typename F>
    bool do_job(F f) {
        if (auto p = pointer.lock()) {
            f(*p);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    void destroy() {
        do_job([](auto& v){
            // Inform your library to remove the shared_ptr.
            v.release_itself();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but maybe it would be trouble to implement the `release_itself` method, so I prefer Yakk - Adam Nevraumont's idea.

Comment: Maybe a (observer) pointer on the `std::shared_ptr` stored in your library might be enough, hard to go further without knowing how you handle lifetime of that `std::shared_ptr`.